# lists and line breaks issues/questions in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I want to fix some behavior with lists and newlines in org-mode I am finding. I use [org-autolist](https://github.com/calvinwyoung/org-autolist) for context.

Issue 1 - If I have an indented piece of text under a list item and I export to latex, it gets rendered in the pdf as being on the same line as the line above. Instead I want it to be treated as part of the list item, just on the line below. For example...

```
1) This is a list item
   This is some text below the list item
```

will be rendered in the pdf after latex export as

1. This is a list itemThis is some text below the list item

whereas I want...

1. This is a list item

   This is some text below the list item

This goes along with another issue where I'd sometimes like to split lines in a way that exports accordingly to latex. For example,

```
Here is a line
This is a line below the line above
```

gets rendered in my pdf as...

Here is a line This is a line below the line above

whereas I'd like...

Here is a line

This is a line below the line above

Issue 2 - I was hoping to make it where I could change some of the behavior of `org-autolist`, to where I can quickly cycle through list options with `Enter`. Currently, I have a list item and press `Enter` I will get a new item. For example...

```
1) This is a list item
```

Pressing enter should give...

```
1) This is a list item
2) <cursor>
```

After this, if I press `Enter` again, I will exit the list. Instead, I'd like to add a step before this, where pressing enter produces the fix to the issue above. For example...

```
1) This is a list item
2) <cursor>
```

after pressing enter should give...

```
1) This is a list item
   <cursor>
```

Then lastly after pressing `Enter` again, I'd want...

```
1) This is a list item

<cursor>
```

Another hope with this would be to define a key binding to indent the region by list-levels.

Lastly, I have some issues with the alignment of tables under list items which I think is an issue with [valign](https://github.com/casouri/valign). If I try to create a table with an horizontal line in it starting at a cursor position that is indented by some amount, I get something like...

```
| This   | is      |
|---------|----------|
| poorly | aligned |
```

Comment: One question per question, please. For the first issue, does it work if you append "\\" (i.e. two backslashes) to the end of the line(s) where you want the newline to appear?

Comment: Yes. That does work. It's not very aesthetic, though. I was hoping more for a function where I could manually insert a line break w/ enter which would produce the `\\` in the .tex file and render appropriately.

Comment: You can control whether newlines in the Org file are taken literally or not by `#+OPTIONS: \n:t` or `#+OPTIONS: \n:nil`, respectively. The option goes on its own line anywhere in the Org file.

Comment: @Tobias Adding `options: \n:t` fixes issue 1. Thank you. If I can somehow figure out how to create a function that works with or replaces `org-autolist` to modify the cursor placement after pressing `Enter` that would make everything look perfect.